# jquery not showing expected results

Tags: jquery

Is jquery lib not working? what is the error here? can anyone help?My HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            $('#dialog').dialog();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none">Some text</div>
<button id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors? Remember to include jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jQuery UI as well, as `dialog()` is not part of jQuery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});            
        $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and you have to initialize the dialog ***before*** you call open, not after

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3rUSL/2/)

Comment: hey, thank you very much!, i wrote the script at the end in the body and it worked! thanks again :)